Arranging $(\sin x)^{\sin x}$, $(\sin x)^{\cos x}$, $(\cos x)^{\sin x}$, $(\cos x)^{\cos x}$ in increasing order, for $x\in (0,\pi/4)$
Arrange in increasing order:
$t_{1}=(\sin x)^{\sin  x}; t_{2}=(\sin x)^{\cos x}; t_{3}=(\cos x)^{\sin x}; t_{4}=(\cos x)^{\cos x}$ where $x \in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$.
What I try: $\sin (x)\in \bigg(0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg)\Longrightarrow \sin(x)=\frac{1}{2}$.
And we have $\cos(x)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.
So $t_{1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=0.7,t_{2}=\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}$
$t_{3}=\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}},t_{4}=\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\bigg)^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}$
How can I compare above result?

Hint: first compare $\sin x$ to $\cos x$.

$$t_{1}=(\sin x)^{\sin  x}\quad t_{2}=(\sin  x)^{\cos x} \quad t_{3}=(\cos x)^{\sin x} \quad t_{4}=(\cos x)^{\cos x}$$
$$x \in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

As you can see $\cos x>\sin x$ for $x \in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$;
$0<\sin x< \frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}<\cos x< 1$
let $\sin x = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} - \delta$ and $\cos x = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} + \delta$
$$t_{1}=\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt2} - \delta\right)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt2} - \delta}\quad t_{2}=\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt2} - \delta\right)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt2} + \delta} \quad t_{3}=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2} + \delta\right)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt2} - \delta} \quad t_{4}=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2} + \delta\right)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt2} + \delta}$$
Setting $\delta$ to a very small value,
$$\boxed{t_3>t_4>t_1>t_2}$$

However coming to how do you compare two expressions, with different bases and exponents, we can go for making the exponents the same;
$t_{1}=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^\frac{1}{2},t_{2}=\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}\tag1$
$ t_{3}=\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}},t_{4}=\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\bigg)^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}\tag2$
in $(1)$, square on both sides, we get
$$\left(\frac12\right)>\left(\frac12\right)^{\sqrt3}$$
we know as $(a)^n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for $|a|<1$
$$\implies t_1>t_2$$
in $(2)$, square on both sides, we get
$$\left(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right)>\left(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right)^{\sqrt3}$$
$\frac{\sqrt3}{2}<1$, this also as previous case can help us conclude the following;
$$\implies t_3>t_4$$
Compare $t_1$ and $t_4$ in a similar manner as we find; $$\implies t_4>t_1$$
You can keep extending this process and conclude ${t_3>t_4>t_1>t_2}$
